Should I ask my dana back?
I gave money to the monk and some layman of monastery via internet because I didn't know that it's prohibited. Will I get demerit? Should I ask money back to redirect them in the right way?
Thank you.

Did you transfer to a personal bank account? If not, why should it be prohibited? Some background may be helpful. As far as I'm know, some monasteries such as Metta Forest Monastery, do accept donations via internet transfer e.g. PayPal.

Yes, I did in both cases. But in the second one it was kappiyas account.

It is fine if it is a temporary measure, take a look at my answer. However, there should be a proper bank account under the monastery's name in the long run for the purpose of collecting donations as well as accounting and auditing purposes.

Most Buddhist monks & monasteries are directly or indirectly in receipt of money because they depend on donations.
If a monk uses or handles your donation inappropriately, the demerit falls upon the monk.
More information on this subject is at this link: Vinaya Class Money and also at page 280 of this link: The Buddhist Monastic Code.
In summary, there is zero chance of any demerit accruing to you. Instead, your donation (if viewed correctly) should be the cause of your rebirth into heaven.

Thank you for your answer, but what about MN 55 Jivakasutta, where the one who gives monks unallowable food gets demerit?

MN 55 is an explicit teaching. Where as monastery bank accounts meant to be administered by laypeople. This said, sure, there are always debates about the purity of this. You may wish to read this link: https://vinaya-class.github.io/13-money.html

It is uncommon that a personal bank account is used to collect donations for a monastery. The issue is that if this account also contains the individual’s funds, then both the monastery’s funds and the personal funds would be mixed up, making it hard to keep track of the movements and purposes. Sometimes, this happens if the monastery is relatively new and in the process of being built. Meanwhile, a managing committee or proper process/procedures had not yet been established. A personal account could have been quickly set up to start collecting monies from ardent supporters to fund the building process while a proper bank account under the monastery’s name is being set up. I am not privy to this matter but in the long run it would be better to setup a separate bank account under the monastery’s name as most if not all monasteries are legal entities by themselves.
There is no demerit if you have justified concerns about the legitimacy of the collection and have supporting evidence to ask for the donation back. Although, you would have to gather sufficient evidence thus it would be quite a hassle in my mind. Personally, what is important for me, is the good intentions behind the dana and sufficient care (within our limited personal capacity, of course) was taken to ensure it was for a legitimate cause. Beyond that, it is hard, as donors, to know how our donations are eventually utilized. Personally, I think after the dana had been performed, we should reflect and rejoice at our good deeds. There was a story behind Dhp 355 in which a very rich man was also very stingy to both himself and others so much so that he, himself, hardly gets to enjoyed his wealth. The reason for his miserliness was explained by the Buddha as the regrets he felt after performing dana in a previous life.
Some of us may take the story above with a pinch of salt but there are a few things that can be learnt from it. First, by reflecting and rejoicing immediately after performing a good deed, we are rewarding ourselves instantly with inner happiness. We don’t need to wait till the karmic fruits of our good deeds to ripen. Second, by not regretting our kind acts, we prevent this type of reaction from becoming habitual. Third, although I still haven’t figure out how such regrets lead to stinginess but it is a fact that such regrets soil our inner happiness. Fourth, by associating joy and happiness with good deeds, it will motivate us to perform more good deeds in future and strengthen our practice in dana.

I don't see why it would be an issue, and you didn't provide any detail on why it would be prohibited, but if they think it's inappropriate, they should send it back without you having to ask. Under most circumstances it would be very unseemly to give a gift and then ask for it back. If sending cash or check is prohibited, they should put a notice on the website, and if there is no notice, that's not your fault. But supporting the Sangha is good, and you don't make bad karma by doing good things, that doesn't stand to reason.

It is impossible, mendicants, it cannot happen for an unlikable, undesirable, disagreeable result to come from good bodily conduct. ...from good verbal …good mental conduct. But it is possible for a likable, desirable, agreeable result to come from good bodily conduct. ...from good verbal …good mental conduct. -AN 1.287-289


The point is that according to the rules of Vinaya, monks can't use money.

I know they're not allowed to handle money, but it's not prohibited for money to be used to buy the things they need. You said you sent it to a monk AND some laypeople. Presumably the laypeople are there to take care of things like that on behalf of the monks and the monastery.

Yes, I read about kappiyas, but there is a source that tells that they are also prohibited: https://pathpress.wordpress.com/2010/08/25/the-use-of-money-by-monks/

But even that article doesn't argue that it's absolutely prohibited, it says the Buddha made exceptions to some rules, for practical reasons, and he points out that, "What is proper depends, of course, on one’s circumstances." For the legalistic side of the issue, he says there are several exceptions in the rule book, including for laypeople who live too far away from the monk and need an intermediary to hold the money for a robe, specifically, til a monk needs it.

And that in that case, "All financial arrangements are made between laypeople without involving the monk. The monk’s involvement extends no further than to request a robe at the time he needs one. 4) Until the robe is purchased, the funds for it belong to the donor. The monk has no control over the money, and it would be an impropriety for his to ask that it be user for anything other than a robe."

Yes, I agree that in some circumstances it can be allowed. And I find it strange that in wilderness there will be no food but kappiya's money can be useful. Maybe this money can be used for creating provision?

Oh, yeah, there aren't too many grocery stores to spend money at in the wilderness. And yeah, that article does say there's a "Mendaka allowance" where they could bring food with them, but only til the journey is over, it sounds like.
